# obtain list of files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

To obtain the list of files, what is wrong with the code below because it does not provide the list.

```
import glob 
file_list = glob.glob('C:/test/*.txt') 
out_file = open('C:/test/out_file/out_file.txt', 'w') 
for i in file_list: 
    out_file.write(i) 
out_file.close ()
```

Comment: You don't get any output *at all*?

Comment: the output are not in the format of list C:/test\1.txtC:/test\2.txtC:/test\3.txtC:/test\4.txtC:/test\5.txt

Comment: You *shouldn't* get any output, since you haven't printed anything. You should get a list of filenames written to the file, assuming the file opens and writes succeeded, although they'll be all on one line since you're using `write`.

Comment: yes, how can i change them into the list? i want to write the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken the liberty in re-factoring your code to improve it a bit, and to correct the problem with newlines you were having:

```
from glob import glob

with open('C:/test/out_file/out_file.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write('\n'.join(glob('C:/test/*.txt')))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the newline:

```
for i in file_list: 
    out_file.write(i + '\n')
```

or use `print()`:

```
for i in file_list: 
    print(i, file=out_file)
```

Writing to a file does not automatically add newlines; only `print()` does that.

Comment: Or, the more compact `out_file.writelines(list(file_list))`

Comment: Just an alternative: `print(*file_list, sep='\n', file=out_file)`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: No, `.writelines()` does *not* add newlines. You'd use `out_file.writelines('\n'.join(file_list))` instead.

Comment: `out_file.writelines('\n'.join(i for i in file_list))`

Comment: Thank you very much for such useful codes.How can I go ahead? I have five text files each of 7 columns by 9 rows as follows:

file_one = 'C:/test/1.txt'
file_two = 'C:/test/2.txt' 
. . . 
file_five = 'C:/test/5.txt'
I have to calculate mean of first row for each file, if mean of first column of each file is 50                                   input_files = print (file_list)  ?

Comment: @keirawilson: I saw that question; same comment here: do not use separate variable names for all those files. Use a list instead. Then work from there. Try to do what you want with 2 files, work your way up.

Comment: Okay, I could obtain list of files using print (file_list) and trying with only five files. How to read all five input files?

Comment: @keirawilson: You know how to loop over a list already; opening a number of filenames listed in a list should be trivial from there.

Comment: sorry, no idea ahead. following code did not help                                for i in file_list: 
    file_list.read(i)

Comment: @keirawilson: you need to *open* a file before you can read it. `open(i).read()` might work better for you..

Comment: import glob 
file_list = glob.glob ('C:/test/*.txt')
for i in file_list: 
    open (i).read()                                           resulted error                                               Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/test/test", line 4, in <module>
    open (i).read()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 634: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @keirawilson: On Python 3, `open()` opens the files in text mode, and you appear to have a file that contains more than just ASCII data. Either specify an encoding (`open(i, encoding='<valid encoding for the files')`) or open in binary mode (`open(i, 'rb')`).

Comment: encoding method worked! thank you very much for your nice guide. for further help, i will ask a new question